# What does this command mean?

Tags: matlab

I am unable to interpret the following command in a MATLAB code

```
while (fa > 0) == (fb > 0)
```

I thought it says: if `fa>0 , fb > 0` and both are equal to each other then do some commands.

However, while running in debug mode, at I found that even then `fa` and `fb` were `< 0` and not equal to each other, the commands were still executed.
May someone kindly help in correct interpretation of the command

This is the beginning of a while loop

Thanks

Comment: It says, "if both expressions have the same truth value, do something."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fa > 0` returns a true/false vector for each entry, which is true iff the entry is positive.

Therefore, `(fa > 0) == (fb > 0)` is true iff all corresponding entries of `fa` and `fb` ahve the same signs.

In other words, $fa = [1,-1]$ and $fb = [-1,1]$ would cause it to be false, but $fa = [-1,-1]$ and $fb = [-2,-3]$ would make it true.

Answer (score 0):

`fa>0` is a boolean value, meaning it evaluates to either `true` or `false`.
The same is true for `fb>0`
So this is stating that if both `fa>0` and `fb>0` evaluate to true, then do the stuff in the loop.
Likewise if both `fa>0` and `fb>0` evaluate to false, then you still do the stuff in the loop.
This is because `true=true` and `false=false`

Comment: what if `fa` and `fb` are vectors?

Comment: I'm not familiar with matlab, but it seemed that OP was confused about `fa>0` being boolean, and how to evaluate such expressions.  Their comment seems to indicate that they thought they were comparing the values of `fa` and `fb`.  @gt6989b

Comment: You are, of course, correct, but $fa$ and $fb$ are most likely to be vectors, not scalars, as that is the most common instance of Matlab operations...